# How to use ng-translate within placeholder attribute?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to use [ng-translate][1] module within the html placeholder attribute? So I can populate the actual data dynamically according to the user language locale?
I have the actual language translations stored as JSON files.

Comment: Well that should actually work. Could you setup a plunk please so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 6):

You should actually be able to just do

```
placeholder="{{translationid | translate }}"
```

Comment: Is there an option also for dynamic translation?